# How to rebind jQuery script after it has been called used once?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have three things going on:

**I am sending information with this form.**

```
<form method="post" id="myForm" action="includes/functions.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="$group_id" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submit_join"/>
    <button class="request" id="sub" name="submit_join">Join</button>
</form>
```

**This jQuery script runs a PHP script.**

```
$("#sub").click(function() {
 $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(){ $("#sub").html("Applied").fadeIn().addClass("applied").removeClass("request"); 
   });
});
$("#myForm").submit(function() {
  return false; 
});
```

**This is what the PHP script does. (Not a prepared statement)**

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_join'])) {
  //User ID
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
  $group_id = $_POST['group_id'];

  $sql="INSERT INTO group_assoc (user_id, group_id, permission, dateTime) VALUES ('$user_id', '$group_id', 0, now())";
  if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
  }
}
```

-It works just fine when someone clicks the button once.

- It triggers the jQuery script
- The jQuery script triggers the PHP script
- The PHP does its job
- The jQuery removes the class "request" and puts a class "applied"

**Problem:**
When the same user clicks another button (meaning a duplicate of the button that they just clicked), the page ignores the jQuery script and does what it would normally do, refresh the page. This is the unwanted process.

**Why several forms and therefore why several buttons?** I am doing a PHP while loop for every group in the website and every form contains a button (Join) that allows you to join the group and change the value on the database using the jQuery script above.

**Question:** How can I rebind the jQuery script so that when another button (`<button class="request" id="sub" name="submit_join">Join</button>`) is clicked, it will **not** ignore the jQuery script?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are working with duplicate IDs, try with classes instead of id

```
<form method="post" class="myForm" action="includes/functions.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="$group_id" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submit_join" />
    <button class="request" class="sub" name="submit_join">Join</button>
</form>
```

and

```
$(document).on('submit', '.myForm', function () {
    return false;
})
$(document).on('submit', '.sub', function () {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.post($form.attr("action"),
    $form.serializeArray(), function () {
        $("#sub").html("Applied").fadeIn().addClass("applied").removeClass("request");
    });
})
```

Comment: I plugged everything in place and it reloads the page. Any idea why?

Comment: did you make the changes in the html also

Comment: Indeed I did. I tweaked it a bit. I changed .myForm to #myForm again, as well as the class="myForm" to id="#myForm" and it refreshed the screen.

When I try to do it with the code provided (unaltered) it does not do anything at all.

Comment: @TiffanyLowe you should not do that... it should be as I gave in my answer... there should not be two elements with the same id

Comment: I know what's going on.

$(document).on('submit', '.myForm', function () {
    return false;
})

This piece of code is preventing anything from happening. It is not letting anything below it to fire. That is my guess.

The code as it is, it doesn't fire. When I plug in both the HTML and the jQuery, the buttons do nothing at all. They just click.

The PHP script is not fired at all.

Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Its always a good idea to pass in the event to the event handler, and do a `event.preventDefault()` to avoid browser's default behaviour on the elements.

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); 
});
```

As for the multiple forms, you can use one handler to handle form submits. `$('#sub')` will bind to only the first button on the page, use a class to attach to multiple buttons of the same type which will still be inefficient. Here is a sample :

```
$('.subbtn').click(function(e){
    var $form = $(this).parents('form'),
        subUrl = $form.attr('action');    

    e.preventDefault();
    $.post(...)  ;  
})
```

This handler should take care of your requirement. You can however use a single handler attached to the common wrapper of the forms (worst case 'body') to improve efficiency.

Comment: If I place the first segment of code provided, will it not fire the form at all since it is placed before anything else happens?

Comment: the snippet will prevent browser based handling of form submit. Since you are implementing your own form handler, it will not affect your form handler.

Answer (score 0):

Like what jagzviruz said, it's always best to use the submit event's event handler to prevent the page refresh. And also, make sure you don't have any duplicate element IDs.

My approach would be something like this: (untested)

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" class="myForm" action="includes/functions.php">
<input type="hidden" name="group_id" value="$group_id" />
<input type="hidden" name="submit_join"/>
<button class="request" class="submit" name="submit_join">Join</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(".myForm").each(function() {
    var $form = $(this),
        action = $form.attr('action'),
        $submit = $form.find('.submit');

    $form.submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        return false;
    });

    $submit.click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.post(...);
    });
});
```

It's pretty much the same solution as what jagzviruz proposed, but I prefer to do things like this inside an `.each()` for clarity.